# Why can't I connect to my wireless network at work?

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I can connect at home, but not at work. I can see the SSID, but it won't connect. I don't see any errors using dmesg either when trying to connect.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion below?  If it worked for you, mark the answer as accepted.  If not, please provide more hardware info so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing this happen lately.  Unfortunately the exact cause is unknown, however it seems as though there may be some issues with 802.11n compatibility.  This worked for me (type these in a terminal):

```
# put down eth0 so it doesn't interfere
sudo ifconfig eth0 down

# disable n
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Hopefully that helps.  If it does, you'll have to type those in a terminal each time you reboot.  I made it into a bash script that I just run when I first log in.  You may wish to do the same.

EDIT:

Since you're using a Broadcom card, you may try adding pof's PPA and installing his fixed driver.  I have never done this before myself, so I can't vouge for it's efficacy.  However it may solve your problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:poliva/pof
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

You can read more about [this fix here](http://pof.eslack.org/2012/05/23/why-broadcom-80211-linux-sta-driver-sucks-and-how-to-fix-it/).

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I've been very busy at work. Here's the hardware info and I will try the suggestion tomorrow at work:

Comment: description: Wireless interfaceproduct: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n
Wireless LAN Controller
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
logical name: eth1
version: 01
serial: ec:55:f9:a1:88:8d
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
resources: irq:19 memory:f0100000-f0103fff

Comment: I tried modprobe -r iwlwifi and received missing module name.

Comment: @Shawna.k.a.abdalShakur Ammended answer above with something else that might help.

Comment: I couldn't get that repository to load. Furthermore, the computer is busted now, hardware issue so no need for this any more. Thanks for the help.